# Tor does not connect----The probable cause: The security system CYBEROAM

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, censorship

My college has installed a security system called Cyberoam. Now they have blocked many things including youtube, break, etc., as a counter measure, I tried to find a way to circumvent this security package/firewall. That is how I came to know about Tor. But even Tor is not working? Can somebody tell me how can I use Tor in a secure environment managed by cyberoam security package/firewall? Or if there is any other way to circumvent this package?

Comment: Did you try with a VPN?

Comment: @Pielco11 Yes, I tried openvpn. It didn't worked.

Comment: When you tried bridges, what did you tried exactly?

Comment: @Pielco11 I sent a email to tor and got bridges. In tor bundle, in tor bridges configuration, I entered custom bridges that I received in the email and tried to connect. But I got "Unable to create a encrypted directory connection."

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9601) old ticket, you'll probably have to use [pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en)...

Comment: Hye! Thank you for answering. It's new year holidays. I will try this when I get back to college and get back to you.

Comment: Meanwhile, what I deciphered from above post is that It may work if I use obfs3 bridges on port 443.

Answer (score 1):

Try to seed your Tor instance outside your firewalled network, i.e. via another network exit(wifi, cell, etc.). After that try to use your pre-seeded instance inside the system. And - try to do the same with I2P, and if it will work - use it as HTTP(S) proxy for Tor if you're unable to do the dir connection. Also please post your `torrc` and Tor output - I will be able to help you further then.

Comment: `Try to seed your Tor instance outside your firewalled network, i.e. via another network exit(wifi, cell, etc.). After that try to use your pre-seeded instance inside the system`  . yes! that works. but why?

Comment: @kashish because seeding makes an actual node addresses available offline from your instance's folder data, i.e. it can learn about very new exits, guards, e.t.c. - not blocked by censoring h/w and s/w

Answer (score 0):

I think DNS traffic is not blocked/censored by Cyberoam. In that case, there is a way to tunnel your IP traffic over DNS. Have a look at [iodine](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/) and here are [instructions](http://hblok.net/blog/posts/2013/04/24/iodine-ip-over-dns/) to set it up.

Typically you will need to do the following -

1. Get a VPS server (digitalocean, linode and like) and install iodine server on it. (cost: ~$5)
2. Buy a domain name, if you don't have one. The create a sub-domain and point it's nameserver to your VPS server IP. (cost: ~$8)
3. Lastly install the iodine client on your computer and start tunneling traffic via it.

The above does require basic familiarity with linux and some monetary investment on your part.

**Alternatively**: Most common proxy servers are blocked via a backlist. So if you pay for your own VPS server (about $5), you can also install an HTTP proxy on it. It should be quickest way to get started.